# kubernetes pod always ContainerCreating but never ready

Tags: kubernetes

TL:DR  ContainerCreating state of pod, Docker containers paused, /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml is reported missing in the logs but does exist and present in `systemctl status kublet`.  On an AWS EC2 details below.

I have a home brewed Kubernetes cluster on an amazon EC2.

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo 
[kubernetes] 
name=Kubernetes 
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7\$basearch 
enabled=1 
gpgcheck=1 
repo_gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg 
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg 
exclude=kubelet kubeadm kubectl 
EOF
```

`sudo yum -y install docker iproute-tc kubelet kubectl kubeadm --disableexcludes=kubernetes`

```
/usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1

/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_ADD_RUNTIMES --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd
```

Then docker, containerd, and kubelet were all enabled and started.

Ran `sudo kubeadm init`

At this stage the node is not ready.

Next I ran:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
```

Flannel here may be a red herring but it seemed to make progress.
The node now shows ready.

I created a deployment.yaml file based on this:  https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/

`kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

Tried Weave in a vein hope:

`kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"`

Allow pods to schedule on the master node:  `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`

The pod shows as ContainerCreating.  So I guess this is where it gets interesting as we now enter the realm of the logs.

`kubectl get events --all-namespaces  --sort-by='.metadata.creationTimestamp'`

Too much to paste here but lots of lines looking like  `Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox`

The command `docker ps` reports that all containers are paused.

`journalctl -u kubelet`

The first error shows:

```
server.go:198] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml", error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory
```

`ls -alh` shows the file exists and is 876B.

None of my research seems to address these underlying issues, please help...

Comment: Are you using specific tutorial ? Can you describe nodes and fetch logs after applying command kubeadm init ?

Comment: I am not using any specific tutorial.  I can describe nodes and fetch logs.  kubctl works fine.  Only it looks like there is something missing.  I am guessing to do with networking but I'm not sure what.  I don't even know how to find the CNI version, if that's different from the kubelet version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CNI version is put in [kube-flannel.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml)  file in ConfigMap configuration.

```
cni-conf.json: |
    {
      "name": "cbr0",
      "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "type": "flannel",
          "delegate": {
            "hairpinMode": true,
            "isDefaultGateway": true
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "portmap",
          "capabilities": {
            "portMappings": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

But the`/etc/cni/net.d` directory with the default location in which the scripts will look for net configurations.

Check following steps:

> 1. Make sure  [all requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/)
>    are filled.
> 2. Make sure you don't block egress traffic and that port  `6443`  ingress rule is open for the worker node (relevant for the joining
>    phase) - check firewall rules.
> 3. Check if  [required ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports)
>    are not occupied.
> 4. Restart Kubelet with  `systemctl restart kubelet`  and then check latest logs with:
>    `sudo journalctl -u kubelet -n 100 --no-pager`.
> 5. Check if Docker version can be updated to a newer stabler one.
> 6. Try running  `kubeadm reset`  and make sure you re-run  `kubeadm init`  with latest version or with the specific stable version by
>    addding  `--kubernetes-version=X.Y.Z`.

Read more:  [kubelet-kubernetes-config-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276901/kubernetes-1-12-2-failed-to-load-kubelet-config-file-var-lib-kubelet-config-yam).

Also if you are using CRI-O - see solution [kubeadm-crio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675268/kubeadm-v1-18-2-with-crio-version-1-18-2-failing-to-start-master-node-from-priva).

Take a look on similar problems: [vpc-cni-k8s](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/1314), [rbac-flannel-kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac).

Comment: @StephenFeyrer Any progress? Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?